# Why is my WPF window loading slowly?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to design what is a pretty simple interface that shows a number of images and then rating buttons.  Here is the XAML.

```
   <Window x:Class="ASU_Evaluation2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:ASU_Evaluation2"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="686" Width="1154" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Closing="Window_Closing">

    <Grid Name="ReviewData" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="205"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="474*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">

            <ToggleButton Content="Cell is good" Name="tbGoodCell" Height="30" Margin="1,1" IsChecked="{Binding Cell_Good}"  Width="200"/>
            <ToggleButton Content="Recon is good" Name="tbReconGood" Height="30" Margin="1,1" IsChecked="{Binding Recon_Good}"  Width="200"/>
            <ToggleButton Content="Stain is good" Name="tbStainCell"  Height="30" Margin="1,1" IsChecked="{Binding GoodStain}"  Width="200"/>
            <ToggleButton Content="Recon Clipped" Name="tbReconClipped"  Height="30" Margin="1,1" IsChecked="{Binding Clipping}"  Width="200"/>
            <ToggleButton Content="Interesting" Name="tbInteresting"  Height="30" Margin="1,1" IsChecked="{Binding Interesting}"   Width="200"/>
            <ToggleButton Content="Background Noise" Name="tbNoisy"  Height="30" Margin="1,1" IsChecked="{Binding Noisy}"  Width="200"/>
            <ToggleButton Content="Has Rings" Name="tbRings"  Height="30" Margin="1,1" IsChecked="{Binding Rings}"  Width="200"/>
            <Label Content="Interfering Object" Margin="1,10,1,1"></Label>

            <ListBox Name="tbInterferingObject"  Height="70" SelectedIndex="{Binding InterferingObject}"  Width="200">
            <ListBoxItem>None          </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Close         </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Far           </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Side    </ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>

            <Label Content="Comments"/>
            <TextBox Margin="1,5" Height="400" Name="Comments" Text="{Binding Comments}" Width="200"/>

        </StackPanel>

        <ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="themes" Width="150" Height="20" SelectionChanged="themes_SelectionChanged" SelectedIndex="0" />
        <TabControl Grid.Column="0"  Name="tabControl1" >
            <TabItem Header="Recon View" Name="tabItem1">
                <Grid Height="612" Width="934">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="225" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="225" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="225" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="225*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="291" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="291" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"   Margin="2,2" Name="MIP_Image" Height="210" Width="210"/>
                    <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"   Margin="2,2" Name="Axial_Image" Source="{Binding Axial_Image}" Height="210" Width="210"/>
                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"   Margin="2,2" Name="Sag_Image" Source="{Binding Sag_Image}" Height="210" Width="210"/>
                    <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"   Margin="2,2" Name="Z_Image" Source="{Binding Z_Image}" Height="210" Width="210"/>
                    <Image Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"   Margin="2,2" Name="Fly_Through"  Height="210" Width="210"/>
                    <Image Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="2,2" Name="Background"  Source="{Binding Background}" Height="250" Width="450"/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Alignment View" Name="tabItem2">
                <Grid >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="460" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="460" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="190" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="190" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="190" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"   Margin="2,2" Name="PP1"   Source="{Binding PP1}" Width="460" Height="190" />
                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"   Margin="2,2" Name="PP2"   Source="{Binding PP2}" Width="460" Height="190" />
                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"   Margin="2,2" Name="PP3"   Source="{Binding PP3}" Width="460" Height="190" />
                    <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"   Margin="2,2" Name="Centering" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="400" MinHeight="400"  Source="{Binding Centering}"/>

                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Stack View" Name="tabItem3" GotFocus="tabItem3_GotFocus">
                <Grid >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="418*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="24*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="581*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="207*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Name="Stack_Image" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100"   Height="400" Margin="98,26,82,15" Width="400" />
                    <ScrollBar Grid.Column="1" Height="353" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,50,0,0" Name="StackZPosition" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="17" ValueChanged="StackZPosition_ValueChanged" />
                    <Label Content="Z Position" Grid.Column="1" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,17,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="79" />
                    <ProgressBar Grid.Row="1" Height="14" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="95,4,0,0" Name="StackProgress" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="404" />
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Othogonal View" Name="tabItem4">
                <Grid >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="418*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="24*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="581*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="207*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

the class that is bound looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ASU_Evaluation2
{
class DatasetExample
{
      public string Date { get { return "3/3/3"; } }
    public ImageSource ExampleImage
    {
        get
        {
            string exampleImage = TopDirectory + @"\data\CrossSections_X___TIK.jpg";

            if (File.Exists(exampleImage))
                return BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(exampleImage, UriKind.Absolute), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
    public bool Recon_Succeeded { get { return true; } }
    public bool Cell_Good
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public bool Recon_Good
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string DatasetName { get; private set; }
    public string TopDirectory { get; private set; }


    string VGFolder;
    string StorageFolder;
    string DehydrateFolder;
    string BackupFolder;
    string StackFolder;
    string StackReportFilePath;

    private void BuildPaths()
    {
        string dirName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(TopDirectory);
        //return dirName;
        string[] parts = dirName.Split('_');
        string Prefix = parts[0];
        string Year = parts[1].Substring(0, 4);
        string month = parts[1].Substring(4, 2);
        string day = parts[1].Substring(6, 2);

        VGFolder = Path.Combine(@"y:\", Prefix + "\\" + Year + month + "\\" + day + "\\" + dirName);
        StorageFolder = Path.Combine(@"z:\", Prefix + "\\" + Year + month + "\\" + day + "\\" + dirName);
        DehydrateFolder = Path.Combine(@"e:\", Prefix + "\\" + Year + month + "\\" + day + "\\" + dirName);
        BackupFolder = Path.Combine(@"V:\BackupCompleted\", Prefix + "\\" + Year + month + "\\" + day + "\\" + dirName);

        if (Prefix.ToLower() == "cct001")
        {
            StackFolder = Path.Combine(@"V:\Raw PP\cct001\Absorption\", Year + month + "\\" + day + "\\" + dirName + "\\STACK\\000");
        }
        else
            StackFolder = Path.Combine(@"V:\Raw PP\", Prefix + "\\" + Year + month + "\\" + day + "\\" + dirName + "\\STACK\\000");

        StackReportFilePath = VGFolder + "\\FixedStackReport.xml";
    }

    public DatasetExample(string name, string path)
    {
        DatasetName = name;
        TopDirectory = path;
        GoodStain = true;
        Clipping = false;
        Interesting = false;
        Noisy = false;
        Rings = false;
        InterferingObject = 0;
        Comments = "  ";
        Evaluator = "Brian";
        Cell_Good = true;
        CellType = " ";
        Recon_Good = true;

    }

    public string Evaluator { get; set; }
    public string CellType { get; set; }
    public bool GoodStain { get; set; }
    public bool Clipping { get; set; }
    public bool Interesting { get; set; }
    public bool Noisy { get; set; }
    public bool Rings { get; set; }
    public int  InterferingObject { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }



    public ImageSource Axial_Image
    {
        get
        {
            string exampleImage = TopDirectory + @"\data\CrossSections_X___TIK.jpg";

            if (File.Exists(exampleImage))
                return BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(exampleImage, UriKind.Absolute), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
    public ImageSource Sag_Image
    {
        get
        {
            string exampleImage = TopDirectory + @"\data\CrossSections_Y___TIK.jpg";

            if (File.Exists(exampleImage))
                return BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(exampleImage, UriKind.Absolute), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
    public ImageSource Z_Image
    {
        get
        {
            string exampleImage = TopDirectory + @"\data\CrossSections_Z___TIK.jpg";

            if (File.Exists(exampleImage))
                return BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(exampleImage, UriKind.Absolute), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
            else
                return null;
        }
    }


    public void ClearMemory()
    {



    }

    public ImageSource Background
    {
        get
        {
            string exampleImage = TopDirectory + @"\data\background.tif";

            if (File.Exists(exampleImage))
                return BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(exampleImage, UriKind.Absolute), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
    public ImageSource PP1
    {
        get
        {
            string exampleImage = TopDirectory + @"\data\projection1.jpg";

            if (File.Exists(exampleImage))
                return BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(exampleImage, UriKind.Absolute), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
    public ImageSource PP2
    {
        get
        {
            string exampleImage = TopDirectory + @"\data\projection2.jpg";

            if (File.Exists(exampleImage))
                return BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(exampleImage, UriKind.Absolute), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
    public ImageSource PP3
    {
        get
        {
            string exampleImage = TopDirectory + @"\data\projection3.jpg";

            if (File.Exists(exampleImage))
                return BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(exampleImage, UriKind.Absolute), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
    public string Centering
    {
        get
        {
            string exampleImage = TopDirectory + @"\data\centering.avi";

            if (File.Exists(exampleImage))
                return exampleImage;
            else
                return "";
        }
    }

    public ImageSource Stack_Image
    {
        get
        {
            string exampleImage = TopDirectory + @"\data\CrossSections_Y___TIK.jpg";

            if (File.Exists(exampleImage))
                return BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(exampleImage, UriKind.Absolute), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
            else
                return null;
        }
    }

}
```

}

It takes 15-20 seconds to load the interface on a high end computer.  I have tried to run the performance monitor tool with the windows SDK and it just crashes.  What am I doing wrong?  This is a embarrassingly simple task in winforms.

Comment: your're doing a lot of expensive stuff (IO operations on files..etc) on the UI thread, do all that on a different thread (not the MAIN UI thread), and let UI know via PropertyChanged, event, or whatever when done processing.

Comment: I think you should use another event (firing after window is shown).

Comment: I did a test and took the same dataset class and used it to load a winform application (changing the bitmapsource for bitmap) https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63600049/Interface2.png The winforms interface loads in 1-3 seconds, while the WPF interface takes 45-60 seconds.  Is the IO handled differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your properties are returning a NEW instance of `ImageSource` every time they're called. you Should avoid this.

- Fix 1:

  ```
  private ImageSource sag_Image;
  public ImageSource Sag_Image
  {
      get
      {
          if (sag_Image != null)
              return sag_Image;

          //... Etc your code

          sag_Image = //Assign the backing field to use it later.
      }
  }
  ```

You should [Freeze your Freezables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509.aspx) (such as `ImageSource`).

- Fix 2:

  ```
  public ImageSource Sag_Image
  {
      get
      {
          if (sag_Image != null)
              return sag_Image;

          //... Etc your code

          sag_Image = //Assign the backing field to use it later.

          sag_Image.Freeze(); //Notice the Freeze() method.
      }
  }
  ```
- Fix 3:

  Async. All operations that take more than 10 ms to complete **SHOULD** be async.

Third, your XAML looks like it was obtained from the Visual Studio designer, and also has some suspicious things such as the `ScrollBar.ValueChanged` event. What is that doing? Post the relevant code, and probably a screenshot of what you need. I'm sure there is a right way to do it WPF which does not involve horrible code-behind winforms type of hacks, and does not show these performance issues you described here.

Comment: I agree, but besides your suggestions - maybe he should use separate thread to do that time-expensive stuff?

Comment: This is the result after the first load.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63600049/Interface.png

The slow motion load is on the first load (as well as all the following), so I do not thing that your suggestion for the new is applicable to the first load (I will use it for the following loads)

I have tried to put as much code into threading as possible, but I still get the same horrible performance (In the treeview to the left)


I have a winform and java application that load the same number of images and put them on the screen in a fraction of the time. Just hoping for cooler GUI

Comment: @ochensati the WPF `TreeView` is not [Virtualized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879.aspx#Container) by default. You will have do some custom virtualization if you have large number of items there.

Comment: @ochensati yeah? really? how did you manage to introduce such a rich layout in the (crappy dinosaur) winforms `TreeView`?... sounds like a partial truth (read: lie) to me.

Comment: The $ScrollBar.ValueChanged event requests a image from a huge 3D chunk of data, cuts it down to size, turns it into a bitmap, which is then changed to a bitmapsource and then displays it on the screen.  This is working and is fast, which is why i do not understand what is wrong with the rest

Comment: @ochensati Try Freezing Freezables. That makes a huge difference.

Comment: @HighCore, I don't understand?  This is the WPF interface?

Comment: @Ochensati you just said you have the same application in winforms. Which sounds really unfeasible to me. Try Freezing Freezables.

Comment: @HighCore The winforms one is ugly and gray.  It does the same thing, but way faster.

Comment: @ochensati **DID YOU TRY** Freezing Freezables? This is the third time I suggest that to you. By the way, I insist to see the winforms `TreeView` with all that UI content there.

Comment: I am getting there.  I am checking the speed of the IO operations. ;-)

Comment: @HighCore With Freezing, it takes 60 seconds to load a dataset.

Comment: @ochensati can you `really` isolate the delay to the code you posted here? remove all the other stuff, treeview and such. Otherwise use some profiler tool to find out what's taking so long. it definitely is not WPF. it is your code.

Comment: I turned off the treeview, themes and put the load data command inside a button so there is no confusion between the program start and the data load.  Here is the output of performance profiling https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63600049/profile.png, as an example, I quickly put together a winform application using the same data backend (class dataset with bitmapsource changed to bitmap)   the wpf loads the data within 60 seconds.  The winform application can do it in 3. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63600049/Interface2.png

Comment: Look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx#perforator) to understand how to read those values. Also your second screenshot shows a blank tab with no images or stuff. That's why you're not getting any values in the profiling tool.

Comment: That was the performance as the slow motion load executes. It goes back to zero once the images are loaded.  I think that I am going to work with winforms for now as I am working on a deadline and winforms has better support for the 3D graphics that I will be using (ITK/VTK).  Thank you for your time.